# Wordpress + Codeigniter htaccess confusing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have Wordpress installed in the root directory with the following htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and I have Codeigniter installed in a sub-directories named members, with the following htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /members/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|templates|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

When I try to access any controller via : site.com/members/controller/function I get the Wordpress 404 error page

Comment: i dont understand why do you need to install codeigniter in a sub directory of wordpress. Why dont you use different directories?

Comment: Wordpress is installed in the root directory, and I will have only the possibility to install Codeigniter in a sub-directory.

Comment: I find it easier to install both in the root directory, and then inject wordpress views into codeigniter views. I've gone through the pains of trying to get wordpress and codeigniter to play nice together, and I highly advise against it.

Comment: I second the pain of getting them to work together.  You have overlapping functions in the helpers, etc. etc. Constant pain.  Can't wait for namespace-leveraged installs, but not holding breath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your CI config.php, set your base url as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://site.com/members/'
```

and change

```
 RewriteBase /members/
```

to

```
RewriteBase /
```

in your CI .htaccess file. This way when you access CI, it doesn't look in the root (which is WP), it goes straight to it's directory and bypasses WP.

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cidir
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```